# Python Flask - How to start python server using flask and execute it multiple times using multiple argumens

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have tested basic Flask script (hello.py) and it is working fine. I have commented out the main function routing part and just executed the script.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

''' #Commenting the Main function part
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

As expected, the server is started and I got the following message as well :

```
C:\>python hello.py
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

**Now my requirement is once this python server is started, how to execute another python script and route to this python server.**

For example I have the following script which needs to be executed via browser (since the python server is already up and running) by accessing http://127.0.0.1:5000/arg1/arg2

```
import .....
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<string:arg1>/<string:arg2>')
def main():
    do something ........
    call sub-function(arg1, arg2)
    do something ........

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arg1 = 100
    arg2 = 50

    #app.run(debug=True) **#I should not run this again as server is already started.So commented it out**

    main(arg1, arg2)    #Calling Main function using two IDs as arguments.
```

**Note : If i keep app.run() in the actual program script which needs to be executed, then it is working fine. But my requirement is server start script actual program script should be different but somehow interlinked via app. I am not sure how to achieve this.**

Comment: If I'm understanding this.... You can import python script... put your `my_script.py` file in the same directory as the flask app and do `import my_script`. Keep in mind, if this does some long-running task, you may want to consider looking at `celery`

Comment: I have a feeling you are overcomplicating things a little bit. Can't you just import `app` created in one file inside of another one?

Comment: @JKC what are you trying to achieve from this? If you want to use a code fragment in other file you can just import it wrapped on a class. or you should call an __init.py__ file before any of this and make it call all the other python files like in flask framework

Comment: Thanks mic4ael. reply to @sytech as well. The thing is if I keep app within the same program script or import the app_start script and execute within the program script, the server will get started again I believe. I do not want this to happen. My requirement is like start the server once and execute the program with different arguments at different times.

Comment: @TharushaShehan . Thank you for your response. I need to achieve executing the same program script with different arguments at different times. But the python server should be started only once. Is this possible by any chance or everytime the app.run() should be invoked which will create new web links for every unique arguments i use ?

Comment: @TharushaShehan . Can you please elaborate on this ? sorry I am a dumb head when it comes to web services, api, python flask, etc.... How to call any API once the server is started. And the server should be started only for once or for every APIs, it needs to be started separately

Comment: Dear @JKC sorry for above comment. my comment is longer than the above one. but the internet connection messed up that's why it looks a little dumb. no offense sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162958/discussion-between-tharusha-shehan-and-jkc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it seems that you want the same API(with the same port number all the time) to be called when you run the python script. that can be done by adding`app.run(port=50000, debug=True)` at the end.

And place all `@app.route()` in that same python script (App.py) by migrating body of the `Def methodName():` to a different Python script in the same directory and calling that by adding`from .SubScript import *`

The SubScript.py files has to have classes to be called in App.py as objects. and in those classes methods needs to be called `def methodName(self):` in order to be run as an object

This way you have clean and organized code base to use with python flask. If you can use the Pycharm editor the process will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks. That helps

Comment: Glad to be of some help. Hope this gives you enough narration to the solution.